# OPENSSL with c++ and posix

Tags: c++, unix, ssl, posix

I have a quick question. I set this client up as a sort of example, so I do not do a lot of extra work with it; I wanted to get the basic idea working first. I have it working so far, with one exception:

If I start it up, I can see the data being sent across on the other side (I use python+twisted). I can write with no problems, the problem comes when I read. On the server side, I am able to see the text coming in and being sent back out again. But on the client side, things are delayed. I have to send three commands to see something coming out.

for example:

I send `hello <newline> cruel <newline> world<newline>` and get `hello` echoed back to me, only after I hit enter on `world`.

Could someone point out why or give me some hints?

Here is the code.

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cstdio>

//used for printing an error and then exiting.
inline void error(const char* message)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", message);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
//the buffer size we will be working with:
#define MAX_BUFF 4096

int main()
{
  int ret; //used for holding bytes read.
  int flag = 1; //our IOCTL flag.
  char buff[MAX_BUFF]; //a buffer for holding i/o data.
  fd_set rdesc, wdesc, srset, swset; //file descriptor sets.
  timeval tv; //used for holding the time select should wait.
  SSL_CTX* context = NULL; //ssl context.
  SSL* ssl = NULL; //main ssl object.
  sockaddr_in addr; //server socket address.
  int sock = 0;
//clean out the struct:
  bzero(&addr, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
//then fill it in.
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port = htons(4000);
  inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &addr.sin_addr.s_addr);
//create the socket
  sock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sock < 0)
    {
      error("Error creating initial socket.");
    }
//initialize SSL.
  SSL_load_error_strings();
  SSL_library_init();
//create the ssl context
  context = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_client_method());
  if (!context)
    {
      error("Could not create SSL context.");
    }
//connect the socket to the server.
  if (connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(sockaddr_in)) < 0)
    {
      error("Could not connect to specified socket.");
    }
//create the ssl object.
  ssl = SSL_new(context);
  if (!ssl)
    {
      error("Could not create ssl object.");
    }
//try to set the socket as the fd for the ssl object.
  if (!SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock))
    {
      error("Error, could not bind fd to the ssl object.");
    }
//link ssl up with the socket.
  if (!SSL_connect(ssl))
    {
      error("Could not perform ssl handshake.");
    }
ioctl(sock, FIONBIO, &flag);
//set our file descriptor sets.
  FD_SET(fileno(stdin), &wdesc);
  FD_SET(sock, &rdesc);
//wait for data, read, then print.
  while (1)
    {
//we need to zero out our i/o buffer.
      bzero(buff, MAX_BUFF);
//initialize our temp fd sets.
      srset = rdesc;
      swset = wdesc;
//each time select finishes it changes this to how much time it actually slept, so we     need to reset it.
      tv.tv_usec = 50*1000; //50 ms
      tv.tv_sec = 0;
//perform the actual select operation.
      select(sock+1, &srset, &swset, NULL, &tv);
//check to see if data was written on stdin (user input)
      if (FD_ISSET(fileno(stdin), &swset))
        {
//read inputted data.
          ret = read(fileno(stdin), buff, MAX_BUFF);
          if (ret)
            {
//write it to the socket.
              SSL_write(ssl, buff, ret);
            }
        }
//check to see if we received anything.
      if (FD_ISSET(sock, &srset))
        {
          printf("in if.\n");
//read it
          ret = SSL_read(ssl, buff, MAX_BUFF);
          printf("%d\n", ret);
          if (ret)
            {
//write it to screen.
              printf("%s\n", buff);
            }
        }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is. A minor nit: the comments in your code are not terribly helpful. Comments should explain why the code is written the way it is, not what it's doing.

Comment: Yes, those comments are worse than useless. They are a distraction that tells you nothing you couldn't figure out by reading the code right next to the comment. The comment at the beginning of the loop and some of the variable comments are sort of useful, but that's it.

Comment: Also regarding the comments, why bother having a variable named `ret` that is then commented as "used for holding bytes read"?  How about naming the variable `bytes_read`?